# Netbeans remote c++ development

Tags: c++, compilation, netbeans-7, remote-debugging

My netbeans project is c++ application based on windows , compilation in on Linux (VMware).

Project need to use some additional library for compilation. path and library names I added to
General, C++ Compile and Linker window in project properties.

**Compilation result is:**

```
Copying project files to /root/.netbeans/remote/10.10.10.191/diman-pc-Windows-x86_64/ at root@10.10.10.191:22
"/usr/bin/gmake" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/root/.netbeans/remote/10.10.10.191/diman-pc-Windows-x86_64/N/VS_netbeans2/audioLoader'
"/usr/bin/gmake"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/audioloader
gmake[2]: Entering directory `/root/.netbeans/remote/10.10.10.191/diman-pc-Windows-x86_64/N/VS_netbeans2/audioLoader'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
g++ -m32    -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/audioloader build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/341086193/CAudioFileLoaderControl.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/341086193/audioLoader.o -L../../dclib/ebsdk/lib -lEb -lEbOS 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lEb
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/audioloader] Error 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/root/.netbeans/remote/10.10.10.191/diman-pc-Windows-x86_64/N/VS_netbeans2/audioLoader'
gmake[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/root/.netbeans/remote/10.10.10.191/diman-pc-Windows-x86_64/N/VS_netbeans2/audioLoader'
gmake: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

It mean that netbenas can't find libraries that I added .

1. When I start compilation netbeans copy all projects files into folders it created in Linux host. *(CHECKED)*.
2. From addition library path I provided it copy only `*.so` files and not copy `*.a` files *(CHECKED)*.

How to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It mean that linker cannot find libEb on path -L../../dclib/ebsdk/lib.
It's not netbeans error.